# Pass DialogFlow session ID as a url parameter on a button

Tags: webview, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger

I am trying to implement a facebook webview with Dialogflow chatbot

I can't find a way to pass back data from web view to the conversation.

What I am now exploring is if it's possible to pass the session ID of the conversation thread from where the button was clicked as a query parameter on the button url.

This way, I can use detect-intent to do something with the data and post a response back to the thread

Answer (score 0):

`            MessengerExtensions.getSupportedFeatures(function success(result) {
                let features = result.supported_features;
                console.log(features);

```
            if (features.includes("context")) {
                MessengerExtensions.getContext('APPID',
                    function success(thread_context) {
                        console.log(thread_context.psid);
                        // success
                        document.getElementById("psid").value = thread_context.psid;
                    },
                    function error(err) {
                        // error
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                );
            }
        }, function error(err) {
            // error retrieving supported features
            console.log(err);
        });`
```

`<input type="hidden" name="psid" id="psid">`

You will get sender ID and based on that you can find session ID if you are Mapping the sender with session ID.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil Savaliya Would you kindly guide me on getting session id (representing the current conversation thread for the current user) from the psid. I am a bit stuck there

Comment: You  need to set sessionID with your user's senderID when user starts the conversation. `let users = {}; users[senderid] = "sessionid"..

Answer (score 0):

You can use getContext() function from Messenger Extensions SDK. 
getContext() gives you thread_context object, which contains tid (The ID of the thread the webview was opened from.).

See this reference: [MessengerExtensions.getContext()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-extensions-sdk/getContext)

Comment: thread_context.tid gives me the page scoped user Id which is different from the sessionId required by detectintent